# making my UID work the same on all servers

Tags: bash, bashrc

I have a user id on 5 servers with the same user name.  On one of the servers I have modified my .`bashrc` and added a bunch of new features to customize my need.

What is the best way for me to have all five servers with the same configuration of that UID. so that I can use them all consistently and keep any changes in sync

They are all FreeBSD servers.

Answer (score 1):

You could check your .bashrc into some sort of version control system such as Git or SVN and have the file regularly pulled down from the repository to each server. If you then update the file on a single server you can push it back up to the main repository to be pulled down to each server from there.

It would be best to create this is as a symlink to a file within version control, say you wanted to use GIT @ BitBucket for example, you could follow the instructions at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Create+an+Account+and+a+Git+Repo.

Once that has been done you can check the repository out on each server, setting up a cron job to do a git pull in your GIT repository at a predefined interval (every 30 minutes?).

Then each time you change the file on any server you can simply do a git commit & git push back up to the main repository and the files will be automatically pulled back down to each server by the cron job.

If you need any further information on any of that I'll be happy to help.

Comment: sounds like a possible option. I am setting up GIT on one of the servers as a private repo so i could do that

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use centralized log in servers and storage (via NFS or automounts)

I'd recommend a mixture of OpenLDAP and Kerberos with NFSv4; however, there are several others such as Samba, just using OpenLDAP, NIS+, or manually syncing files.

These all should be readily available in `ports` and in `pkg`. As a heads up, you'll need to adjust `pam` as well.

Comment: my servers are all FreeBsd and I use SSH to log in to each would ldap give me a common .bashrc for each ??

Comment: @MB. no, LDAP (and LDAP\Kerberos) would give you the same password and uid\gid across all machines. If you want the same `.bashrc` then you would want centralized storage like NFS and possibly automounts.